# C# MVC3 and Membership keep me logged in (remember me)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership

I'm using Membership features in my application and I have the following logIn code:

```
if (!Membership.ValidateUser(email, password))
{
    ViewBag.Message = "E-mail ou senha estão incorretos.";
    return View();
}
else
{
    FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(email, password);
    var keep = keepMeLoggedIn == "true,false" ? true : false;
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, keep);
    return Redirect("~/Home/Mural");
}
```

From yesterday to now, when I openned my app again, I was not logged in...
I heard about that when you generate a persistent cookie the session never expires, is that true? What I'm doing wrong? Should I put some information else in web.config?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Usuario/Login" protection="All" timeout="360"   cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" />
</authentication>
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keep = keepMeLoggedIn == "true,false" ? true : false;
```

This code worries me a little. However, I don't think that is causing the problem.

But, a persistent cookie has an expiration (timeout) which is determined, in what you showed, the authentication tag.

The only difference between a session cookie and a persistent cookie, is that a session cookie will expire if the user closes the browser or when it is timed out. A persistent cookie will only expire when it is timed out.

The second parameter of SetAuthCookie is whether or not to create a persistent cookie. If false, it will be a session, if true, it will be persistent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer TIHan, I would like my session never expires, if the user chooses the persistent login. How could I do that?

Comment: I think the only way to do that is to just increase the timeout. It's in minutes, so 26280000 is 50 years. Which I think is enough time. :)